# No custom query option in my highlighted Content

Tags: web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages

I created a page and added a Highlighted content web part. I wanted to target a specific library so I wanted to add a custom query. However, I don’t see anywhere the option for Custom Query inside my highlighted content .

I want to see something like this

[image]

I only see the normal form.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your tenant is in the standard release mode.

This capability is currently rolling out and available in targeted release tenants.

[image]

You can change the release mode of your tenant as mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide). Would suggest that you change the mode only if its a demo or acceptance environment.

Reference - [Microsoft 365 Roadmap link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/roadmap?rtc=2&filters=&searchterms=caml)